# Is there a way to input a newline in a textarea with Laravel Dusk?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I am trying to add an input consisting of multiple lines to a textarea.

The textarea:
`<textarea dusk="input-field"><textarea>`

I have tried multiple ways of making this happen, but none of them work.
This is the base code:

```
/**
     * Testing if submitting a batch is successful.
     * @test
     * @return void
     */
    public function correct_batch()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                    ->type('@input-field', 'input')
                    ->press('@submit-button')
                    ->assertSee('success');
        });
    }
```

I have tried the following in the command `->type('@input-field', *input*)`, namely:

```
'input1', 'input2' > only inputs input1
'input1\ninput2' > inputs it as a text in full
'input1<br>input2' > inputs it as a text in full
```

The problem is solely with the input.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `"input1\ninput2"` work? (using double quotes instead of single quotes)

Comment: It does Tim Lewis, thank you!

Comment: Sweet! I was hoping it was as simple as that :) Typically, escaped strings, like `"\n"` and `"\t"`, don't function in single quotes, only in double quotes, and HTML is valid in textareas, so `<br/>` is treated literally.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that!